# Angular form validation hint printing

Tags: angular

i am building a form in angular, and i'm using validators for each field, the html form looks like this :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
      <mat-form-field>
        <label translate>Name field</label>
        <input formControlName="name" matInput>
      </mat-form-field>
...
```

And in the .ts file i initialize the form with:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeForm();
  }

  initializeForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      nameControl: new FormControl(this.initialShare?.name, [Validators.required, noWhitespaceValidator]),
      ...
    });
  }
```

noWhitespaceValidator is a custom validator that checks if the user input consists of only whitespaces.

My question is, how could i add a piece of text that shows which validator does not pass, for example, i want to print: Name is required, if the Validators.required fails, or , Name cannot be composed of only whitespaces, if the noWhitespaceValidator fails.

Comment: you can do that by implementing a snackbar/modal/dialog when validation of the form doesn't pass..

Comment: @iLuvLogix The main issue is that i don't know how to check if validation passes and more exactly, which validator

Comment: You could use i.E. ngif `<div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].invalid && (form.controls['name'].dirty || form.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert">
            <div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].errors.required">
            Please enter username
          </div>` Just an example, formfield-names and validators need to be changed to whatever you have ..

Comment: See -> https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-display-validation-messages-using-angular for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Material Inputs you can show your errors using `mat-error`

**Like This**

```
 <mat-form-field>
        <label translate>Name field</label>
        <input formControlName="nameControl" matInput>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('nameControl').hasError('required')">Name is required</mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('nameControl').hasError('THE_ERROR_NAME_THAT_IS_RETURNING_FROM_VALIDATOR')"> Name cannot be composed of only whitespaces</mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**`THE_ERROR_NAME_THAT_IS_RETURNING_FROM_VALIDATOR` field should be replaced with the key which is returning from `noWhitespaceValidator`
validator

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly with a small complain, the error message appears only after i switch to another field, couldnt it be set to appear realtime? After each keystroke for example?

Comment: It is the default behavior of Material Form Field Elements, the error is visible when the `formControl` is touched and invalid. The `formControl` will be marked as touched on the `blur` event(when the Input lost focus), so it means on the second time when the user start typing on the touched input, the error will appear/disappear during users typing

Answer (score 0):

It's like @iLuvLogix said in comments

```
<div *ngIf="form.controls['nameControl'].errors.noWhitespaceValidator class="alert">
   Name cannot be composed of only whitespaces
</div>            
<div *ngIf="form.controls['nameControl'].errors.required">
         Name is required
</div>
```

see this link: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: I read that article, but if i try to use *ngIf="form.controls['nameControl'].errors.CUSTOM_VALIDATOR_NAME" it doesnt work for no reason, any ideas?